# Which g++ switches would help me write good code, like -Wall -Werror?

Tags: c++, g++

I just got into C++ programming. Which commandline switches are a good idea to use in order to help me code?

I'm learning C++ by writing some small programs. I want my code to be as good as possible (at the expense of development and compilation time). For instance, switches that warn about portability problems, undefined behaviour and non-idomatic code would be useful.

I know of `-Wall -Werror`. Are there others?

Comment: There are many, many others. Which ones you need depend very much on the specific circumstances. See [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++) for a list of G++'s command line options.

Comment: What's the use case? g++ has like a billion switches.

Comment: @Mac I'm learning C++ by writing small programs here and there. The `g++` man page is way too long for me to go through it for all useful switches.

Comment: At the very least, I tend to use `-Wextra` -pedantic-errors` and one of the standards: either `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++98`

Comment: `-pedantic`, or better yet `-pedantic-errors` in order to ensure that your code is standard and more portable, if that's something you're interested in.

Comment: I'm learning C++ by writing small programs. I want my code to be as good as possible at the expense of development and compilation time, so e.g. all lint-like switches and warnings about portability and undefined behaviour are welcome.

Comment: `-Wextra` has been mentioned and is good, but keep in mind that `-Wextra` also enables some questionable diagnostics. When you get warnings, try to look more at why you get them. If you've examined the "why" and determined the warning is appropriate because your code does something weird, only then try to rewrite the code to something that does not warn. If you've examined the "why" and determined that the warning is inappropriate, you feel the code is written exactly the way it should be, don't change the code, suppress or ignore the warning.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about recommendations.


Comment: To add to hvd, some warnings in `-Wextra` are stylistic, and some enabled warnings can have false positive. In those cases, *fixing* the warning can actually make your code awkward. If you find a warning to be dubious, you can ask on here (on SO) why the warning is raised and learn how to deactivate *just this one*. Also, beware that some warnings from gcc are only active when optimizations are used (release mode) because gcc does not bother to run them otherwise. If you want to learn C++, I would recommend switching over to Clang (and use the Clang Static Analyzer for free!).

Answer (score 7):

**A list of *gcc* switches for code quality**

- `-Wall` for most common warnings
- `-Wextra` for even more warnings which are still useful (this used to be just `-W`, if you see that switch mentioned it's same as this).
- `-Werror` to force you to fix warnings by turning them into errors
- `-std=c++11` or whatever to specify [a language standard or dialect](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) (`-ansi` switch, which is sometimes used, is equal to some `-std=X` for each supported language, but I've seen different standards documented at different places...).
- `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors` to tell *gcc* to be strict about the standard

Switches which I believe are not enabled by above (thanks for commenters!), and will help especially when learning, to help see what is happening implicitly. Read more in gcc doc for [warning switches of *gcc*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options):

- `-Wconversion` to force you to use explicit casts for example in cases where there is risk of value overflow and getting mangled value
- `-Wsign-conversion` to force you to use explicit casts when there's risk of value getting mangled due to unsigned-signed conversion

However, *gcc* is not the ideal tool, or only tool you should use.

**Use other tools than just compiler!**

Very important tool is [*valgrind*](http://valgrind.org/), which analyzes memory use of running program, and which you will want to use also in future, whenever you run into memory corruption problems. There are also GUIs for valgrind (check your Linux packages for easy installation), and latest versions of Qt Creator have pretty nice valgrind integration on Linux.

Then there are static code analyzers. Google for "C++ code analyzer" or "C++ lint" and also check the software repositiories of your Linux distribution (assuming you're using Linux, and if not, consider using one in a VM). One possiblity is [C++ Lint](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpplint/), and another one is [Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), though I have not tried either myself

**Peer review**

Nothing is as valuable for learning, as getting your code peer reviewed. However, SO is not the right place for plain review, but there's https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which is in beta, and I think it is just the place to ask if learning code you have written is any good.

Comment: +1 for extending it to lint and other tools for static and dynamic code analysis.

Comment: `-pedantic-errors` and `-ansi` is also good.

Comment: @H2CO3 Edited answer to mention those, thanks! Though I think `-std=` is preferable to `-ansi` in any new project, because I found it being same as `-std=c++98` in one doc, but `-std=c++03` in another...

Comment: Also: use more than 1 compiler. GCC isn't sacred. Neither is Clang. Both have been known to be wrong on occasion.

Comment: @rubenvb exactly. I test a current project of mine with both, and e. g. clang didn't warn me about a non-standard printf conversion specifier, whereas GCC doesn't catch certain unsigned-signed promotions.

Comment: @hyde Fair enough. Does this mean that I'm using my compiler wrong if I specify both `-ansi` and `-std=c89`?

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't know the specifics, but if a Fedora man page is to be trusted ("-ansi In C mode, this is equivalent to -std=c90") it should have same effect as having two `-std=` options. I *think* (did not verify/test, but it would be logical...) that the last switch always has effect, affecting compilation of sources following it in the command line... I've methodically just converted `-ansi` to the right `-std=` when in any doubt, to avoid any surprises.

Comment: @H2CO3 GCC needs `-Wsign-conversion` which is not part of `-Wall` or `-Wextra` for C++. With respect to the `-ansi -std=c89` thing: `-ansi` translates to a `-std=` option, and I believe the last option on the commandline is kept, so although it's not technically wrong, you're confusing yourself. Either use `-ansi` or `-std=...`. Personally I think `-ansi` is unclear as to its meaning.

Comment: @rubenvb thanks, added -Wsign-conversion to answer